# Value mismatched during the add new cell in collection view

Tags: arrays, swift

I have tableview under this tableview cell I was set the new collection view and I need to add new cells on tap of the addmore button, but when I pressed the addmore button with reload the tableview cell the existing collection view cell values are mismatched or reset.
 Any solution for that?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: Thanks for replying on my issue.The issue is resolved.